# In postgres, can errors go into separate log files for each user?

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to setup different log files for each postgres user, so that we can easily separate the errors.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that postgresql.conf has a log_line_prefix configuration that allows for user name and even the session id. I don't think it can be configured to log separately but if the errors are logged with user id then you should be able to filter them easy enough